# Web browser in C# windows application form without using web browser class

Tags: c#, iwebbrowser2

I am trying to do C# web browser(navigate, favorites, display, GUI, history, sending the HTTP request, receiving http the response, bulk download) without using web browser class but I can't find anything related to that could anyone please help me with this concept code. I created the design in the C# windows application form.

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question, do you have a specific question related to what sounds like a project? And if so, can you share what you already tried?

Comment: You can use HTTPRequest or create a controller. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: i just strted to create code but can`t find anything related to that so don't know how to do.

Comment: could you tell me the favorites part how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading files can be done with the WebClient class, but if you want an actual browser and the webbrowser object isn't good enough then I recommend using something like CefSharp.

Comment: Is any tutorial there on how to do it?

Comment: Just google C# CefSharp tutorial